# How to specialize a C++ templated-class function basing on a type-dependent type?

Tags: c++, templates, g++, template-specialization

I have a C++ templated class

```
// Definition
template <typename T>
class MyCLass {
public:
  typedef typename T::S MyS; // <-- This is a dependent type from the template one
  MyS operator()(const MyS& x);
};

// Implementation
template <typename T>
MyCLass<T>::MyS MyClass<T>::operator()(const MyClass<T>::MyS& x) {...}
```

What I want is that overloaded operator `operator()` behaves differently when `MyS` is `double`.

I thought about specialization, but how to do in this case considering that the specialization should act on a type-dependent type? Thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could forward the work to some private overloaded function:

```
template <typename T>
class MyCLass {
public:
  typedef typename T::S MyS;
  MyS operator()(const MyS& x) { return operator_impl(x); }

private:
  template<typename U>
  U operator_impl(const U& x);

  double operator_impl(double x);
};
```

Comment: Overloading is far less redundant than template specializations in my book, YMMV.

Comment: But how about the style of your specialization... you did overload the function... is it another way to get specialization??? Cause I am trying this way but the way I do the compiler gets angry...

Comment: This is the question I created for the problem I mentioned you before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845878/how-to-specialize-a-templated-member-function-into-a-templated-class-in-c

Comment: Another way is the one Yuushi showed. You could make the function a template and conditionaly enable overloads with `enable_if`.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this by introducing an extra default parameter:

```
template <typename T, typename Usual = typename T::S>
class MyClass { ... };
```

Then you can specialize using a `double`:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass<T, double> { ... }
```